# Eas build fails with error:Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.facebook.react:react-native:+]

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, expo, eas

*How to reproduce:*
Run eas build --profile development --platform android for the snack at: https://snack.expo.dev/@vaishsharma/bc062f . The package.json can be checked in the snack project.

*Description:*
I see the below error while building an expo managed app with eas

```
> Configure project :react-native-firebase_app
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/package.json
:react-native-firebase_app:firebase.bom using default value: 31.2.2
:react-native-firebase_app:play.play-services-auth using default value: 20.3.0
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/package.json
:react-native-firebase_app:version set from package.json: 17.3.1 (17,3,1 - 17003001)
:react-native-firebase_app:android.compileSdk using custom value: 33
:react-native-firebase_app:android.targetSdk using custom value: 33
:react-native-firebase_app:android.minSdk using custom value: 21
:react-native-firebase_app:reactNativeAndroidDir /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native/android
> Configure project :react-native-firebase_auth
:react-native-firebase_auth package.json found at /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/auth/package.json
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/package.json
:react-native-firebase_auth:firebase.bom using default value: 31.2.2
:react-native-firebase_auth package.json found at /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/auth/package.json
:react-native-firebase_auth:version set from package.json: 17.3.1 (17,3,1 - 17003001)
:react-native-firebase_auth:android.compileSdk using custom value: 33
:react-native-firebase_auth:android.targetSdk using custom value: 33
:react-native-firebase_auth:android.minSdk using custom value: 21
:react-native-firebase_auth:reactNativeAndroidDir /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native/android
[stderr] 
FAILURE:
[stderr] 
Build failed with an exception.
[stderr] 
* Where:
[stderr] 
Build file '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android/build.gradle' line: 33
[stderr] 
* What went wrong:
[stderr] 
A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-vector-icons'.
[stderr] 
>
[stderr] 
Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.facebook.react:react-native:+] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

I have changed

```
compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
```

to

```
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
```

But, the error still persists. I am not sure why the change is not reflected.
Also, expo doctor cmd returns

```
✖ Verifying prebuild support package versions are compatible failed
Issues:
[stderr] 
Expected package @expo/config-plugins@~6.0.0
[stderr] 
  Found invalid:
[stderr] 
    @expo/config-plugins@5.0.4
[stderr] 
    @expo/config-plugins@5.0.4
[stderr] 
    (for more info, run: npm why @expo/config-plugins)
Advice:
  • Upgrade dependencies that are using the invalid package versions.
- Checking dependency versions for compatibility with the installed Expo SDK...
✔ Checking dependency versions for compatibility with the installed Expo SDK passed
- Validating Expo Config...
[stderr] 
NOT SUPPORTED: option format. `validateFormats: false` can be used instead.
- Validating Expo Config...
✔ Validating Expo Config passed
- Checking package.json for common issues...
✔ Checking package.json for common issues passed
[stderr] 
✖ Found one or more possible issues with the project. See above logs for issues and advice to resolve.
```

@expo/config-plugins@5.0.4 is a dependency of "@react-native-firebase/app": "^17.3.1", "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^17.3.1" which do not support @expo/config-plugins@~6.0.0
Is this causing the build error?
I have been at it for days. Any help is extremely appreciated.